# How can I update a scene in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, scene

I'm trying to learn c++ and for that, I would like to implement a board game (the game of life) in which we have several cells. If the cell is alive, we paint it white, if the cell is dead we paint it black.
What I am trying to do at the moment is simply:

1. make one cell alive
2. show it on screen
3. wait for half a second
4. make another cell alive
5. show it on screen.

However, it seems to me that when the scene is displayed, both cells are already alive. This is the main part of my current code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>

using namespace std;

// global variables:
const int WIDTH = 600;
const int HEIGHT = 400;
const int SIZE = 10;
const int NCOL = HEIGHT/SIZE;

const QColor aliveCol = QColor(200,200,200);
const QColor deadCol = QColor(50,50,50);

class Cell {
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
    bool alive;
    vector<Cell> neigh;

    Cell(int a = 0, int b = 0) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        alive = false;
        neigh = {};
    }

    void draw(QGraphicsScene * scene){
        QGraphicsRectItem * cell1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(this->x*SIZE,this->y*SIZE,SIZE,SIZE);
        if (this->alive) {
            cell1->setBrush(QBrush(aliveCol));
        }
        else {
            cell1->setBrush(QBrush(deadCol));
        }
        scene->addItem(cell1);
    }

};

void updateScene (Cell mat [NCOL][NCOL], QGraphicsScene * scene) {
    for (int i = 0; i<NCOL; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<NCOL; j++) {
            mat[i][j].draw(scene);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    QApplication prog(argc, argv);
    //MainWindow w;
    //w.show();
    /**
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Quit now!!");
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &prog, SLOT(quit()));
    button->show();**/
    QGraphicsScene * scene = new QGraphicsScene(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    //background:
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::gray);

    //build the board
    for (int i = 0; i <= NCOL; i++){
          scene->addLine(SIZE*i,0,SIZE*i,HEIGHT);
          scene->addLine(0,SIZE*i,HEIGHT,SIZE*i);
    }

    //building the cells matrix:
    Cell mat [NCOL][NCOL]={};
    for (int i = 0; i<NCOL; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<NCOL; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = Cell(i,j);
        }
    }

    //(...) <- Non important stuff    

    //step 1
    mat[9][7].alive = true;

    updateScene(mat,scene);

    //step 2
    QGraphicsView * view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->setFixedSize(610,410);
    view->show();

    //step 3 (I know this is not how it is done, but I'm having troubles with QTimer)
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        continue;
    }

    // step 4
    mat[20][30].alive = true;
    updateScene(mat,scene);

    // step 5
    scene->advance();
    scene->update();

    return prog.exec();
}
```

Comment: Your comment “I know this is not how it is done” is correct—to get the behavior you want, you need to use QTimer; delaying within a function call won’t work because the results are not rendered until after the function returns.  QTimer::singleShot() might be useful to you, it will cause a slot to be called after a specified amount of time has passed.

Comment: You need to understand that QT application is an event-based system. Your GUI starts working since call to `prog.exec()`. So, everything you do before, is executed before the QT event loop starts and GUI elements are rendered. I would recommend to start with `class MyMainWIndow : QMainWIndow` implementation and some simple signal-slot connection to trigger rendering of second live cell, e.g. `QPushButton::clicked` can trigger this action (easier for quick testing than a timer).

Comment: I see... I should have just started with something simpler instead. A few changes to the answer below should reproduce what I want, however I really need to dive a bit into the documentation so I can understand what is happening. Advancing the scene with a click and check singleShot() should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed a little your code, I use Mainwindow class instead of using the main function directly and used **QTimer** class and **QRandomGenerator**

the result is this :

**In mainwindow.h** :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

using namespace std;

// global variables:
const int     WIDTH    = 600;
const int     HEIGHT   = 400;
const int     SIZE     = 10;
const int     NCOL     = HEIGHT / SIZE;
const QColor  aliveCol = QColor(200, 200, 200);
const QColor  deadCol  = QColor(50, 50, 50);


class Cell
{
public:
    int           x;
    int           y;
    bool          alive;
    vector<Cell>  neigh;

    Cell(int a = 0, int b = 0)
    {
        x     = a;
        y     = b;
        alive = false;
        neigh = { };
    }

    void  draw(QGraphicsScene *scene)
    {
        QGraphicsRectItem *cell1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(this->x * SIZE, this->y * SIZE, SIZE, SIZE);

        if (this->alive)
        {
            cell1->setBrush(QBrush(aliveCol));
        }
        else
        {
            cell1->setBrush(QBrush(deadCol));
        }

        scene->addItem(cell1);
    }
};

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

    void  updateScene(Cell mat[NCOL][NCOL], QGraphicsScene *scene);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Cell            mat[NCOL][NCOL] = { };
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**In mainwindow.cpp** :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore/QRandomGenerator>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // background:
    scene->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::gray);

    // build the board
    for (int i = 0; i <= NCOL; i++)
    {
        scene->addLine(SIZE * i, 0, SIZE * i, HEIGHT);
        scene->addLine(0, SIZE * i, HEIGHT, SIZE * i);
    }

    // building the cells matrix:

    for (int i = 0; i < NCOL; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j] = Cell(i, j);
        }
    }


    // step 1
    mat[9][7].alive = true;

    updateScene(mat, scene);

    // step 2
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->setFixedSize(610, 410);
    view->show();

    // step 3 (I know this is not how it is done, but I'm having troubles with QTimer)
    QTimer *_timer = new QTimer;

    connect(_timer, &QTimer::timeout, scene, [this, scene]()
    {
        mat[QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(40)][QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(40)].alive = true;
        updateScene(mat, scene);
    });

    _timer->start(500);


   
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  MainWindow::updateScene(Cell mat[NCOL][NCOL], QGraphicsScene *scene)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NCOL; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOL; j++)
        {
            mat[i][j].draw(scene);
        }
    }
}
```

**Out put is :**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I just have one following question. In your code, can I just delete step 5 or will there be consequences in the future?

Comment: yes , I should delete it , it doesn't require.